# Grouping my multiple columns for a single condiiton

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query below that's working but not quite how I want it.

The query pulls phone data for our CSRs and we're currently getting data for 15 agents. The current query gets the totals I need but adds them all up and gives me one line of totals. I'd like to have it showing totals for each CSR. The problem with this is that each call record in the source table has their 4-digit extension as either the calling number or the called number. However, there is no one field that exists in each record to tie that user's extension to the call. It either has to exist as the calling or called number.

So I've got the logic worked out correctly, I believe, except that now I need to group calls by extension. So with 15 CSRs, I want the statement to return 15 rows, each with their own individual totals. But since there's no universal field to group by, I think I would need to group by both fields.

In other words, say "If callingpartyno has 7200 and finallycalledpartyno has 7200, group these as the totals for extension 7200".

Here's an example of how the data looks in the source table:

```
    callingpartyno | finallycalledpartyno 
    -------------------------------------
    1234                outside   
    1234                outside   
    1234                outside   
    outsidecall         1234          
    outsidecall         1234          
    outsidecall         1234          
    9876                outside   
    9876                outside   
    9876                outside   
    outsidecall         9876         
    outsidecall         9876                  
    outsidecall         9876
```

As you can see, nothing identifies each record to the same CSR.

And here is the query:

```
 SELECT

        sum(Duration) AS total_talk_time_seconds
      , round(sum(Duration) / 60,2) AS total_talk_time_minutes
      , sum(if(LEGTYPE1 = 1,1,0)) AS total_outbound
      , sum(if(LEGTYPE1 = 2,1,0) and ANSWERED = 1) AS total_inbound
      , sum(if(LEGTYPE1 = 2,1,0) and ANSWERED = 0) AS total_missed
      , SUM(IF(LEGTYPE1 = 1, 1, 0)) +                   -- outbound calls
        SUM(IF(LEGTYPE1 = 2, 1, 0))  AS total_calls
      , NOW() AS time_of_report
      , curdate() AS date_of_report
FROM cdrdb.session a
    INNER JOIN cdrdb.callsummary b
      ON a.NOTABLECALLID = b.NOTABLECALLID
    where date(b.ts) = '2017-10-16 00:00:00'
    AND callingpartyno IN (7276,7314, 7295, 7306,7357,7200,7218,7247 7331,7255,7330,7000,7215, 7240,7358,7312) 
    OR  finallycalledpartyno IN (7276,7314, 7295, 7306,7357,7200,7218,7247 7331,7255,7330,7000,7215, 7240,7358,7312)
```

So again, the query works to pull records for the specified date, where any of those extensions are in either callingpartyno or finallycalledpartyno, but I need a way to group it by those two and treat each record as the 4-digit extension, almost like a user ID.

Comment: A "dirty" trick for GROUP BY: `GROUP BY callingpartyno + finallycalledpartyno`. According to your sample data, one of two fields will be converted to `0`. This however won't work, if the numbers are not always numeric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what the `group by` clause is for. By inserting a `case` statement, we can create an ID using your own conditions.

```sql
 select
  case 
    when callingpartyno       in (7276,7314,7295,7306,7357,7200,7218,7247,7331,7255,7330,7000,7215,7240,7358,7312)
      then callingpartyno
    when finallycalledpartyno in (7276,7314,7295,7306,7357,7200,7218,7247,7331,7255,7330,7000,7215,7240,7358,7312)
      then finallycalledpartyno
  end as id
  , sum(duration) as total_talk_time_seconds
  , round(sum(duration) / 60,2) as total_talk_time_minutes
  , sum(if(legtype1 = 1,1,0)) as total_outbound
  , sum(if(legtype1 = 2,1,0) and answered = 1) as total_inbound
  , sum(if(legtype1 = 2,1,0) and answered = 0) as total_missed
  , sum(if(legtype1 = 1, 1, 0)) +                   -- outbound calls
    sum(if(legtype1 = 2, 1, 0))  as total_calls
  , now() as time_of_report
  , curdate() as date_of_report
from 
  cdrdb.session a
  join cdrdb.callsummary b
    on a.notablecallid = b.notablecallid
where 
  date(b.ts) = '2017-10-16 00:00:00'
  and (
    callingpartyno           in (7276,7314,7295,7306,7357,7200,7218,7247,7331,7255,7330,7000,7215,7240,7358,7312)
    or  finallycalledpartyno in (7276,7314,7295,7306,7357,7200,7218,7247,7331,7255,7330,7000,7215,7240,7358,7312)
  )
group by
  id -- <-- the calculated field we created in the select clause
```

I've also corrected your `or` statement. Using it outside of parenthesis like you did made the date more or less irrelevant.

Comment: MySQL allows you to use column aliases in the GROUP BY clause. No need to copy and paste a long expression expression.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel: Updated

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest:

```
SELECT sum(Duration) AS total_talk_time_seconds,
       round(sum(Duration) / 60, 2) AS total_talk_time_minutes,
       sum(LEGTYPE1 = 1) AS total_outbound,
       sum(LEGTYPE1 = 2 and ANSWERED = 1) AS total_inbound,
       sum(LEGTYPE1 = 2 and ANSWERED = 0) AS total_missed,
       SUM(LEGTYPE1 in (1, 2)) AS total_calls,
       NOW() AS time_of_report,
       curdate() AS date_of_report
FROM cdrdb.session s INNER JOIN
     cdrdb.callsummary cs
      ON s.NOTABLECALLID = cs.NOTABLECALLID
where date(b.ts) = '2017-10-16' and
      (callingpartyno IN (7276, 7314, 7295, 7306, 7357, 7200,7218,7247, 7331, 7255, 7330, 7000, 7215, 7240,7358,7312)  or
       finallycalledpartyno IN (7276,7314, 7295, 7306,7357,7200, 7218,7247, 7331, 7255, 7330, 7000, 7215, 7240, 7358, 7312) 
      )
group by (case when callingpartyno IN (7276, 7314, 7295, 7306,7357, 7200, 7218, 7247, 7331,7255,7330,7000,7215, 7240,7358,7312)
               then callingpartyno else finallycalledpartyno
          end);
```

Your real problem are the parentheses around the logic in the `where` clause.

In addition, I made the following changes:

- Removed the `if()`.  If you are going to use MySQL extensions, just use the extension that treats booleans as integers.
- Use `in` instead of chained comparisons
- No need to include the time component of a date in the string literal.

Comment: This does a much better job with logic but it still only returns one line of all totals rather than treating the 4 digit extension of each call as the single user extension. So I need it to list 15 rows, one with totals for each extension